# Python: List of sublists, write sublists without brackets

Tags: python, list, csv, brackets

I have a List that is x values long. The list is broken up into different length sublists.I then take these sublists and write them to an output file. Is there a way to print the sublists without the brackets.

Edited to clarfiy:

The *actual* list is 300 sublists long with 12250 elements in it, and changes with each senario I run. Obviously, this is simplified. Let me change a few things and see if that changes the answers.

i.e.

```
List=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15]]
```

where the output is:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15]
```

but I want

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6, 7
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15
```

I want this output in a new variable, say ListMod, so then I can use ListMod in a seperate function to write a file. The file also calls 2 other lists, Time and Size, where Size designates the length of the line in ListMod.

How much does that modify your answers?

Comment: As a side note, there's almost never a good reason to write `for i in xrange(len(List)): foo(List[i])`. Just use `for element in List: foo(element)`.

Answer (score 7):

First, the answer:

```
file.write(','.join(map(repr, List))
```

Your actual code can't possibly be writing what you claim it is, for multiple reasons:

- A file's `write` method will give you a `TypeError` if you give it a list, not print it out. You have to call `str` or `repr` on the list to get something you can `write`.
- Calling `str` or `repr` on a list puts spaces after the commas, as well as brackets.
- You've got at least one `SyntaxError` in your code that would prevent you even getting that far.

So, I have to guess what you're *actually* doing before I can explain how to fix it. Maybe something like this:

```
file.write(str(List))
```

If so, the `__str__` method of a list is effectively:

```
'[' + ', '.join(map(repr, self)) + ']'
```

You want this without the brackets and without the spaces, so it's:

```
','.join(map(repr, self))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your output format appears to be CSV.  If the actual data is as simple as in the example provided, then you can just use python's csv writer:

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerows(List)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Python 3.x or 2.6 onwards and don't mind using `print` as a function:

```
from __future__ import print_function # ignore if on py 3.x

for line in List:
    print(*line, sep=',', file=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print '\n'.join(','.join(map(str, x)) for x in List)
```